# React Native - Translating UI design from Zeplin & layouting for diferent devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native, layout

I'm a noob in react-native development and currently trying to build an app with login, register & some onboarding form.

I already got the UI design from our UI designer in the form of Zeplin. Now that I have that file, the UI/UX designer is putting components across the layout using a fix coordinate position. However, I'm trying to do the layout using flex so that it can fit correctly on different screen size. Below are the screenshot of the UI

[image: Login Page]

[image: Profile Page]

My questions are

1. How would you usually translate the UI design to match your apps?
2. How would you group the component in a viewing this case? (eg: the logo, 'login akun' & lorem ipsum are in 1 view & the text input & login button are in another view, etc)
3. Taking into consideration that this app will be used in many different types of devices, including iOS, is there any guidelines or set of principles that I have to follow to make sure the apps are showing in all devices correctly & in proportional?
4. Is it a good idea to do the layout using a fix height view?
5. When I tried to do the layout using a view, the layout was fine when the keyboard was showing. But on another device with a smaller screen, the components somehow is overlapping each other when the keyboard is showing. How can I avoid this problem?

Thank you very much & looking forward to the enlightenment!